# Randomly coloring sprites, but needs restrictions

Tags: ios, swift, random, skaction

I have a very, very specific issue.

I have six rectangles.

[] = a rectangle.

They have a format like this on the screen: [] [][] [][] [].
They all need to be a random color between red, green, and blue.

```
       var colorize1 = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(.redColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.1)

        var colorize2 = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(.greenColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.1)

        var colorize3 = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(.blueColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.1)

       var actions = [colorize1, colorize2, colorize3]

         var randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))

       var action = actions[randomIndex]





        greenWall1.runAction(action)
        greenWall2.runAction(action)
```

This code does that. BUT, I can't have the same color adjacent to the next pair.

[Wall1] [Wall2][Wall3] [Wall4][Wall5] [Wall6]

1 and 2 are pairs. 3 and 4 are pairs, etc.

Wall 1 and Wall 2 need to be the same color since they're pairs. 3 and 4 need to be a different random color. 5 and 6 need to be a different than WallPair1 and WallPair2.

Right now, I get up to three of the same colors on each pair. Maybe all reds.

I need to write code that says "if pair 1 (wall1 and wall2) are red for example, then the second pair(wall3 and wall4), and the third pair(wall5 and wall6), can't be red.

I can't figure this out.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: The last two lines of yours makes things slightly less clear, as they indicate that you've already created nodes named greenWall1, greenWall2, redWall1 etc. Clearly _these_ can/should not have another color than their name indicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make a bucket and pull your colours from that. 
When the `colorBucket` becomes empty, refill it.

For example.

```
var colorBucket = [UIColor]()

func randomColor() -> UIColor {

    if colorBucket.isEmpty {
        fillBucket()
    }

    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colorBucket.count)))
    let randomColor = colorBucket[randomIndex]
    colorBucket.removeAtIndex(randomIndex)
    return randomColor
}

func fillBucket() {
    colorBucket = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.blueColor()]
}
```

This is the same method Tetris uses to ensure players don't go too long without seeing every shape.

Comment: Would I say greenWall.color = randomColor() ? Do I keep my original code?

Comment: The above code uses a bucket of colors. But you could just as easily switch out the colors with your actions. What you're trying to achieve is that when something is randomly pulled out, there's no chance of the same thing being pulled out again.